# How can I hide the table cells contents dynamically using plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cell

I am creating a table in plain JavaScript, and filling it up using onClick listener event in two ways - either clicking on a external button, or clicking on one of the cells itself.I am not able to hide the contents of my table cells dynamically i.e.I want to hide them when rendering values in them, which I want to unhide/display later-on on some other event.

I have already tried conventional methods available viz.

`td {display: none;},`  and  `td {visibilty: hidden}`

I have also tried inline CSS style method to hide the cell contents, but all these methods blank the table itself i.e. oblivate the cell borders themselves.

```
<body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
           <table id="myelement">
                <tr>
                 <td>&nbsp;</td>
                 ...  ....  ...
                 <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
</body>
<script>
   ...
   for(let i=0;i<mycount;i++){
     for(var t=0;t< Math.floor(Math.random()*td.length);t++){
      td[n[i]].firstChild.nodeValue='X';
      }
    }
    ...
</script>
```

All the techniques available blank the table itself i.e. oblivate the cell borders themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this, and some other ways might be better depending on the content of your table cells. But assuming it's just text, one way you could hide the cell contents would be to make the `fontSize` of the cell equal to 0. See this example:

```js
hide.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  document.getElementById("table").rows[1].cells[1].style.fontSize = 0;
});

show.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  document.getElementById("table").rows[1].cells[1].style.fontSize = null;
});
```

```css
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="hide">Hide Cell "Smith"</button>
<button id="show">Show Cell "Smith"</button>
```

Comment: AndroidNoobie It works fine as a clicking event on a button dedicated for hiding or showing. But it still does not work when  I have a button that provides clicking event for a function call that renders values for table cellls. My requirement is that I shoud be able to hide the cell value as it renders.

Comment: Do you mean you want the text hidden by default? If so, just set the fontSize to 0 in the CSS (similar to my answer above) and then reset it when you want to "unhide" the text.

Comment: For example, `#table td { font-size: 0 }` in the CSS and then reset it when you want to unhide it.

Comment: Again the same thing happened as it was previously. The table went blank and reduced to a minimal size !

Comment: Also you can have a look over here:

Comment: #myelement {
                width: 80%;
                margin: auto;
                border: 0.06em solid #999;
                border-spacing: 0.3em;
                box-shadow: 0.7em 0.7em 0.7em #999;
                background: #a1deee;
             }

Comment: The problem is partially solved -  the "haunted" cell is gone (the target cell content is hidden), but  the basic problem that we are encountering all along -  the cell borders of target cells are also gone -  that is a persistent game spoilover. Just work over there...